# CCProgressTimer doesn't work correctly

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I'm writing a game using CCProgressTimer for HP bar.

Following is my code to add a HP bar:

```
_hpBar = [CCProgressTimer progressWithSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"hp_bar.png"]];
_hpBar.type = kCCProgressTimerTypeBar;
_hpBar.barChangeRate = ccp(1, 0);       //  Y stays the same
_hpBar.midpoint = ccp(0, 0);
_hpBar.percentage = 100;
_hpBar.position = ccp(_hpBar.contentSize.width * scale / 2, self.contentSize.height + _hpBar.contentSize.height / 2 + 2);
[self addChild:_hpBar];
```

Add  this is my code to increase HP:

```
- (int)increaseHP:(int)amount {
    _life = MIN(_life + amount, 100);
    if (_life > 30) [_hpBar setSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"hp_bar.png"]];
    [_hpBar setPercentage:_life];
    return _life;
}
```

However, when the HP is full, namely _life=100, and then I increase some more HP, i.e. calling [self increaseHP:1], the HP bar will disappear.

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Because the percentage goes from 0 to 100 and the behavior for >100% is undefined (not safeguarded).

If your character can have, say 250 HP max, then you need to calculate the percentage of health the character has. If he has 125 HP for example that would make 50%.